# MySQL database one-to-one relation

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

If I have a database with multiple tables all with one to one relations. What is the best approach for when I register a row in one table, it's also registers a row across the related tables. I know you can use cascade to update and delete using foreign keys so is there a similar approach for creating these related rows with default values?

Comment: 1:1 is rarely a useful design pattern.  Why not have all the columns in a single table?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Creating null rows is not great design. Better create them only when necessary using foreign keys. If you still must, look at transactional stored procedures.

Comment: Ok I should have said default. My mistake. It's for a website. So when a user say.... Submitted input, I could then just update that table row etc